# Why is A&B&C a part of A xor B xor C?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am fairly new to set theory and logical operators, and was casually browsing the wikipedia pages on logical disjunction and exclusive or. In the case of two sets, the two operators behave logical by first glance. However, it was the three set venn diagram for exclusive or which stumped me.

What would be a logical and intuitive explanation as to why the intersection A&B&C should be included in the exclusive or of A, B, and C? Especially since A&B is not part of A xor B, the very core essence or difference from normal or.
[A xor B xor C from wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfPSd.png)

Comment: See the [full picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference)... We have $(A \delta B)$. that is what is in $A$ or in $B$ but NOT in both, and then we add (with Symmetric Diff again) $C$. The get the result, you add all $C$ but you have to remove the two slices that are in $A$ and $B$ respectively. But the third slice (the central one) of $C$ is made with the intersection of $C$ with $A \cap B$: but the part $A \cap B$ is not is $A \Delta B$, and thus we have to add it.

Comment: The Symm Diff intuition is exactly that of XOR: in one of the two but not in both.

Answer (score 0):

Since logical value of A xor B is equal to 0 while A is true and B is true, the logical value of something false ( A xor B ) and something true ( C ) for xor is true, therefore the final evaluation is indeed true. It makes sense when you split it like that, as you should because the operator is defined how it works on two operands.

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about $A \oplus B$, where $A$ and $B$ are sets and $\oplus$ is exclusive-or, is that we're choosing those elements $x$ which are in exactly one  out of $A$ and $B$. We are *not* getting elements which are in both, and we are not getting elements which are in neither.

When we extend this to the exclusive-or of many sets, one possible generalization we might think of is that $A_1 \oplus A_2 \oplus A_3 \oplus \cdots \oplus A_n$ should select the elements $x$ which are in exactly one of the sets $A_i$. We could write that as

\begin{align*}
       & A_1 \setminus (A_2 \cup A_3 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) \\
\cup\; & A_2 \setminus (A_1 \cup A_3 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) \\
 \dots & \\
\cup\; & A_n \setminus (A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_{n-1}) \\
\end{align*}
to be really explicit.

This is a perfectly reasonable construction, and I think it's probably what you're thinking about. However, it's not the same as what we actually get when we expand the conventional set-theoretic definition of $\oplus$, namely
$$
   A \oplus B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A).
$$
Working with *that*, we can find an expanded form for $(A \oplus B) \oplus C$, which turns out to be the same as for $A \oplus (B \oplus C)$. So an $n$-ary exclusive-or like the one above, $A_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus A_n$, will also be well-defined; and there are some other pleasant algebraic properties. All of that contributes to why this definition of $\oplus$ is the one that we consider to be "the right one".

What we find with this definition is that the "proper" generalization of exclusive-or is that we will be selecting those elements $x$ which are in *an odd number* of the sets $A_1$ through $A_n$. This coincides with the normal understanding when $n=2$, because the only possible odd number there is $1$. But as in your question, with $n=3$, we find that $A \oplus B \oplus C$ will consist of those elements which are in only $A$, together with those in only $B$, together with those in only $C$ (collectively, the $n=1$ case); *and also* those elements which are in $A \cap B \cap C$ (the $n=3$ case).

Comment: Thanks for the expansion on this, much appreciated. I might have stated it above - I am new to logical operators, and I assumed they would work in the same fashion a function would, i.e ⊕(a,b) behaves similarly to ⊕(a,b,c)